# RecordInvalid Error but parameters being passed are valid as far as I can see

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've currently got three models: Songs have many Setlists and vice versa, through the Allocations model.

I'm trying to use a nested form to add existing songs to a setlist.

My current view for the nested form:

```
<div>
  <%=form_for @allocation do|builder|%>
    <%=builder.label :song_id, "Pick a song" %>

     <%= builder.hidden_field :setlist_id, value: @setlist.id %>

     <%= builder.select(:song_id, options_for_select(@selections), {}, {multiple: true, size: 7}) %>

    <%=builder.submit "Add Song", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and my controller for editing setlists:

```
  def edit
    @songs = Song.all(order: 'title')
    @setlist = Setlist.find(params[:id])
    @allocations = @setlist.allocations
    @allocation = Allocation.new
    @selections = Song.all.collect {|s| [ [s.title, s.artist].join(" by "), s.id ]   }
  end

  def update

    @setlist = Setlist.find(params[:id])
    @selections = Song.all.collect {|s| [ [s.title, s.artist].join(" by "), s.id] }
    @allocations = @setlist.allocations
    @allocation = Allocation.new

    params[:allocation][:song_id].reject! { |c| c.empty? }

    if @setlist.update_attributes(params[:setlist])
      if @allocation.save
        flash[:success] = "SETLIST SAVED!"
        redirect_to setlist_path(@setlist)
      else
        flash[:fail] = "Setlist not saved"
        render 'edit'
      end
    else
      flash[:fail] = "FAIL!"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Whenever I submit the form to add a song to the setlist I get an error back saying:

```
Validation failed: Setlist can't be blank, Song can't be blank
```

All the parameters appear to being passed correctly so I'm stumped. Here's the parameters returned:

```
   {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ThIXkLeizRYtZW77ifHgmQ8+UmsGnDhdZ93RMIpppNg=",
 "setlist"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2012",
 "date(2i)"=>"7",
 "date(3i)"=>"11",
 "morning"=>"false"},
 "allocation"=>{"setlist_id"=>"1",
 "song_id"=>["5"]},
 "commit"=>"Add Song",
 "id"=>"1"}
```

Thank you for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allowing multiple selections in the `:song_id` field, one option of which I imagine has a blank value. That option and one other must be getting selected, causing the `["", 13]` response.

```
params[:allocation][:song_id].reject! { |c| c.empty? }
```

This will clean blank entries from that param. This should be placed in the `update` method anywhere before this line

```
if @setlist.update_attributes(params[:setlist])
```

As for the validation error, I assume it's coming from the `Allocation` since that's what the form is for.

```
@allocation = Allocation.new

if @allocation.save!
```

Not knowing all of the attributes  have attributes here that require values, like `:set_list_id` and `:song_id`. You're trying to persist an `Allocation` to the database without first setting any of it's attributes. This is the likely source of the validation issues you're having.

**Edit:**

A nested form in rails is a set of form fields for an object associated with the object for the parent form. Notice how [this form](http://archives.ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes) has `fields_for` called on the `person_form` object. This will result in nested parameters like `param[:person][:children][:name]`.

```
<% form_for @person do |person_form| %>

  <%= person_form.label :name %>
  <%= person_form.text_field :name %>

  <% person_form.fields_for :children do |child_form| %>
    <%= child_form.label :name %>
    <%= child_form.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= submit_tag %>
```

In the `update` method for this you could have something as simple as

```
person = Person.find(params[:id]).update_attributes(params[:person])
```

The `update_attributes` on Person can manage the creation, updating, and saving of it's `children` association for you with [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

I *think* this is what you're after, and as such you may need to rethink your view and the `update` method accordingly. This is relatively tricky stuff for an absolute beginner to rails; just keep going back to the documentation *(it's very well written)* and asking for help here.

Comment: Sorry for being a bother but I'm a complete newbie, where should I be inserting that code? In my controller under the edit action?

Comment: Updated my answer to specify.

Comment: Thank you. Although the parameters are passing correctly now the application still isn't functioning. I will update the question with regards to what's happening

Comment: I hope my last edit is helpful; I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish with your setup - but it sounds like what I've posted may help guide you.